# Nexus7 can't load native library

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-native-library

I try to build native libraries (in my case SQLite) to add them to my Android project.

My problem: My Nexus7 with Android 6.0.1 tries to load it from the `../lib/arm/libsqlite3.so` path. But this path doesn't exist.

From the beginning:

1. I downloaded the [sqlite-amalgamation-3310100.zip](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)
2. In this folder, I created a `CMakeLists.txt` file with this content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_definitions(-DSQLITE_DQS=0)
add_definitions(-DSQLITE_DEFAULT_MEMSTATUS=0)
add_definitions(-DSQLITE_DEFAULT_WAL_SYNCHRONOUS=1)
add_definitions(-DSQLITE_LIKE_DOESNT_MATCH_BLOBS=1)
add_definitions(-DSQLITE_MAX_EXPR_DEPTH=0)
add_definitions(-DSQLITE_OMIT_DECLTYPE=1)
add_definitions(-DSQLITE_OMIT_DEPRECATED=1)
add_definitions(-DSQLITE_OMIT_PROGRESS_CALLBACK=1)
add_definitions(-DSQLITE_USE_ALLOCA=1)

add_library(
    # Specifies the name of the library.
    sqlite3

    # Sets the library as a shared library.
    SHARED

    # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
    shell.c
    sqlite3.c
    sqlite3.h
    sqlite3ext.h
)
```

3. I built the lib with this command (followed by `make`):

```
~/development/sdks/android-sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/cmake \
    -DANDROID_NDK=~/development/sdks/android-sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669 \
    -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/development/sdks/android-sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
    -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=armeabi-v7a \
    -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang \
    -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a \
    -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=29
```

I did this for this 4 ABI: `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a`, `x86` and `x86_64`.

After that, I copied the `.so` files into the `app/src/main/jniLibs/<abi>` folder, the folder structur looks like this:

```
.
├── app
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── jniLibs
│       │   │   ├── arm64-v8a
│       │   │   │   └── libsqlite3.so
│       │   │   ├── armeabi-v7a
│       │   │   │   └── libsqlite3.so
│       │   │   ├── x86
│       │   │   │   └── libsqlite3.so
│       │   │   └── x86_64
│       │   │       └── libsqlite3.so
```

When I now run the app, I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memcpy"
referenced by "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/lib/arm/libsqlite3.so"...
```

Why does Android try to load the lib from the `lib/arm` folder and not from `lib/armeabi-v7a`? It works when I do the same with a different device with Android 7.1.1.

Btw, The Android Native Lib demo project works too. And when I look into its apk, the native lib is in the `lib/armeabi-v7a` folder. So why does it work when Android Studio compiles the native code but not when I add a precompiled native lib?

Comment: Why are you setting `ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=29` if you're going to run this on an Android 6 device (which is API level 23) ?  The value you set should match your `minSdkVersion`.

Comment: @Michael thanks a lot, you saved my life :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael wrote, I have to set the right `DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL`. To get it running on Android 6.0.1 I have to use API level 23 or below. So the `cmake` command should look like this:

```
~/development/sdks/android-sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/cmake \
    -DANDROID_NDK=~/development/sdks/android-sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669 \
    -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/development/sdks/android-sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
    -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=armeabi-v7a \
    -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang \
    -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a \
    -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=19
```